# getPage function only throws video data

Tags: rfacebook

I have been using the getPage function from the Rfacebook package for a long time to retrieve the post ids from facebook pages, but lately, it only throws the data for videos. Anyone knows why this is happening?

Comment: Update: it seems that this is happening when I try to get information before September of this year

Comment: You can [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/46554070/edit) your post and include the additional info.